# Poincaré perturbation method on Mathieu's equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

I need to solve the IVP $\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}+[\omega^2+2\epsilon \cos(2t)]u=0$; $u(0)=1$, $\frac{du}{dt}(0)=0$ using the Poincaré method of perturbation. However, I have no idea how to start. We weren't given much theory on this method, and were only given a few examples. However, I have no idea how to extrapolate those examples to this equation since I was given is very misleading to me.

The information given is that $u=u_0+\epsilon u_1(t)+\epsilon^2 u_2(t)+...$, and $\omega^2=n^2 +\epsilon \omega_1 + \epsilon^2 \omega_2+...$. So, if this is the information for the solution, does this mean that time does not need to be perturbed? And what does this expansion for $\omega$ mean and why is it justified? Also, should it just be substituted into the equation and then the equation simply needs to be solved without perturbing time? Very weird...

Some help would really be appreciated!

Comment: Try to plug in expression for $u(t)$ into your original equation and group terms with the same order of $\varepsilon$. You'll get power series in $\varepsilon$ with coefficients which are functions of $t$. Equate them to zero. This is where you should start, as far as I understand.

Comment: It's worthwhile to note that $u_0$ is a function of $t$, which solves the unperturbed equation $\frac{\text{d}^2 u}{\text{d} t^2} + n^2 u = 0$. Adding to the advice of @Evgeny, which in itself should help you solve the problem: you can also find the initial conditions for $u_1$ at $t_0$ by evaluating the expansion of $u$ at $t = 0$ and comparing it with the boundary conditions given for $u$. Lastly, as you work out the solutions to the ODEs, notice that $n=1$ is a special case!

Comment: It appears that I also need to substitute the expansion for $\omega$.

Comment: That's true, it's apparently given that $\omega$ is close to $n$. If you do that, and follow @Evgeny's advice, everything should be clear. If things don't work out, feel free to edit the question and add your attempt to the answer.

Comment: @FritsVeerman, why do you refer to $\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}+n^2u=0$ and not to  $\frac{d^2u}{dt^2}+(n^2+... + 2\epsilon \cos (2t))u=0$?

Comment: Because that is the 'leading order' equation, i.e. the equation you get when you substitute $u = u_0 + \epsilon u_1 + \ldots$ and $\omega^2 = n^2 + \epsilon \omega_1 + \ldots$ in the ODE and sort the resulting expression in powers of $\epsilon$, as @Evgeny suggested. The leading order equation is then given by all terms not being multiplied by $\epsilon$ in this case (or by $\epsilon^0$, if you will), which are $\frac{\text{d}^2 u}{\text{d} t^2}$ and $n^2 u$.